# Bug in <unordered_set>?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, std, g++4.8

I am building a header-only library (for good reasons; don't hate) which contains a class and the implementations of the class member functions. In doing so I ran into a very odd error with `<unordered_set>`. Searches of GCC's Bugzilla turn up nothing that seem to address this.

My code which breaks (badly) has the includes inside my namespace.

```
namespace probability {

#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>  // only this include breaks
#include <unordered_map>  

class ProbabilityTools
{
...
```

By chance, I moved the #includes outside of the class namespace and it fixed the problem with `<unordered_set>`. None of the other includes caused this problem when placed INSIDE the namespace, only `<unordered_set>`.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>   // works when outside the namespace
#include <unordered_map>

namespace probability {

class ProbabilityTools
{
...
```

I am using GCC g++ 4.8 with -std=c++11 to build this code which works in the second configuration and works as far as `<unordered_map>` use, in both configurations.

Might this be an libstdc++ bug? GCC bug?

Comment: Don't include standard library headers inside a namespace, that's a bug in your code.

Comment: Note this wouldn't be the STL. It would be the GCC implementation of the C++ standard library.

Comment: The bug is in your code, not in the library. Library includes are not to be included inside namespace.

Comment: Thank you mattnewport and SergeyA! Problem solved. I guess I was just lucky that the other includes tolerated my error.

Comment: No, you were _unlucky_ that they tolerated your error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not place standard `#include` directives inside a namespace.  See C++14 [using.headers]/3 (which is speaking about the standard library's headers):

> A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any external declaration or definition, and shall include the header lexically before the first reference to any of the entities it declares or first defines in that translation unit.

Comment: [LWG 2225](http://wg21.link/lwg2225) already added a "no diagnostic required" for C++14, and [LWG 2428](http://wg21.link/lwg2428) deleted the "external", which is a copy-paste error from C.

Comment: @T.C. OK. [intro.compliance]/1 says "syntactic and semantic rules" require a diagnostic unless otherwise stated, but I wasn't sure which rules fell under that umbrella